# How to set the focus to a text-box using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am trying to set the focus on a text-box using JavaScript but it is not working for me when i run in other words it is not setting the focus on the text-box. What am i doing wrong here?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate() {
             var sleepQuality = document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').value;
             if (sleepQuality == "") {
                 alert("Please enter something....... ");
                 return false;
                 document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').focus();
             }
         }
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: can you inspect the page client side and post that as well, this should show us what the actual value is for <%=txtRate.ClientID %>

Comment: @hamed because not everyone needs to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return exits the function. Nothing after it is executed.

```
alert("Please enter something....... ");
return false;
document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').focus();  //<-- I will not run
```

move it before

```
alert("Please enter something....... ");
document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').focus();  //<-- I will run
return false;
```